# The usage of " the way to go"

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

The way to go is  a phrase used encouraging someone to continue the good work according to Free Dictionary. If we asses its usage in the following context, apparently it was used as a adjective as a part of a sentence not as a independent sentence like " well done" .

So I'd like to ask if this is a standard usage of this phrase and which adjective we can replace with it in the closest sense ? For example "successful" ?

> KMPlayer is designed to be user-friendly and offers a gorgeous looking
>   UI design. While it supports various skins, the default skin itself is
>   a treat to the eyes, sporting a dark framed UI design. Even if you’re
>   not so fond of the default skin, custom skins are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

"Way to go" means the procedure for doing something.  That "something" can be literal, meaning the actual physical path to take:

> What's the best **way to go** downtown?

Or figurative:

> Graduating in three years is the **way to go**.

In the usage above (and in your example of custom skins) it means the best option.

As you've noted, it's also an idiomatic aside, congratulating someone on choosing a successful option:

> You graduated in *two* years.  **Way to go**!

But note its ironic usage:

> Three speeding tickets in two weeks, eh? **Way to go**!

Answer (score 0):

"Good job",
Commendable, 
Admirable,
"On the right path"
Wise, 
I know there are more, but I can't think of them :/